# Angular5 Error While Ngbuild with --prod flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean

I'd like to build my MEAN Stack app with --prod flag. But I got this error on my terminal :

> ERROR in : 'flash-message' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'flash-message' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'flash-message' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("   
>       
>         [ERROR ->]
>         
>        ")

On my app.module.ts I've to import this module:

> import { FlashMessageModule, FlashMessage } from
>   'angular-flash-message';

And while I build it with --prod flag, returns that error. 
Then I tried this [solving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477330/angular-5-flash-messages-is-not-a-known-element)

it gives me another error notification like this :

> [ts] Module
>   '"c:/0Projects/mean/angular/node_modules/angular2-flash-messages/module/index"'
>   has no exported member 'FlashMessageModule'. Did you mean
>   'FlashMessagesModule'?

Everything run alright when I build without --prod flag.

Comment: looking at [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flash-message) you can see that the element is `<flash-messages>` (plural). Perhaps change that somewhere in your code. Also, it seems like the new package is `angular2-flash-message`

Comment: Possibly duplicate question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477330/angular-5-flash-messages-is-not-a-known-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5: 'flash-messages' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477330/angular-5-flash-messages-is-not-a-known-element)